# Yet another Wordpress date range issue

Tags: php, wordpress, date, advanced-custom-fields

Most of the solutions on here assume that you have a single "date" custom field assigned to each post ("event" in this case), however I have two fields - a "from" and a "to" field on each event.

### Requirement

An event can span multiple dates, hence the two fields on each Event (created using ACF). A calendar control on the front end allows the user to select a date range.

### What I've tried

```
$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page'        => get_option('posts_per_page'), 
    'paged'                 => $paged, 
    'post_type'             => 'event',
    'order'                 => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'to_date',
            'value' => date("ymd"), 
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
    'meta_key' => 'from_date', 
);
```

I think this is close, but I'm not getting any posts returned. Any ideas?

### EDIT:

I have also tried the solution listed [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/query-custom-post-types-by-two-custom-date-fields/?replies=12#post-5704878), and while this is VERY close to working, if the event date spans the following dates (for example)

25th Sept 2017
to
30th Sept 2017

And the user sets the dates filter on the website to the following:

27th Sept 2017
to
30th Sept 2017

Then the event above does not display. It will only display when the user selects the "from" date to be prior to the 25th (the start date of the event). I require the user to be able to filter and show events even if they have already started on a date before the "from" date that the user selects, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `meta_query` with a `date_query`.

```
'date_query' => array(
    array(
        'after'     => array(
            'year'  => $from['year'],                   
            'month' => $from['month'],
            'day'   => $from['day'],
        ),
        'before'    => array(
            'year'  => $to['year'],
            'month' => $to['month'],
            'day'   => $to['day'],
        ),
        'inclusive' => true,
    ),
),
```